# BlackJack Card Game: I can create stacks, but can't access them

Tags: java, stack

So this is my main class: It creates a CradStack Object and uses the mixCards method, which you will see in the next class block.

```
package BlackJack;


public class BlackJack {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    CardStack cs = new CardStack();
    cs.mixCards();
    //cs.pop();
}

public BlackJack() {

}

public void calculateHand() {

}

public void compareHands() {

}


}
```

This is the CardStack class: It extends Stack and till now has only the method mix Cards which fills the Stack with 312 Cards (6decks à 13 types à 4 suites and than mixes it with the Collections.shuffle method.
This should work.

```
package BlackJack;

import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Stack;


public class CardStack extends Stack {

public CardStack() {

}



public void mixCards() {
    Stack st = new Stack();

    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {                                           
        for (int k = 0; k < 13; k++) {                                      
            for (int l = 0; l < 4; l++) {                                   
                Card cd = new Card();
                cd.setValue(k);
                cd.setColor(l);
                st.push(cd);
            }
        }
    }
    Collections.shuffle(st);
}


}
```

This is the Card Class: I will implement the suite/color as an enum later on

```
package BlackJack;

public class Card {

private int value;
private String color;
//enum Suit { HEARTS, DIAMONDS, CLUBS, SPADES };

public void setValue(int value) {
    this.value = value;
}

public void setColor(int l) {
    if (l == 0) {
        this.color="Hearts";
    }
    if (l == 1) {
        this.color="Clubs";
    }
    if (l == 2) {
        this.color="Diamonds";
    }
    if (l == 3) {
        this.color="Spades";
    }
}

public int getValue() {
    return value;
}

public String getColor() {
    return color;
}

}
```

Can someone explain why i do get an EmptyStackException when i use cs.pop ?

Comment: because you are trying to pop something off an empty stack

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to create separate Stack in `mixCards` method since your `CardStack` IS a `Stack` (since it extends it).
So simply use `this.push` (you can also skip `this.` part since it will be added by compiler anyway) to add cards to card stack represented by *current* instance of `CardStack`.

BTW. [Avoid raw types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it). If your class is meant to hold cards then you should declare it as

```
public class CardStack extends Stack<Card> {
   ...
}
```

Comment: If you are referring to post right above then it is an *answer*. What you posted now is a *comment*. Anyway you are welcome :)